# Can I deduct an IRA contribution while drawing money from another?

Tags: taxes, tax-deduction, ira, income

can I make a tax deductible contribution to a traditional ira in the same year i withdraw dividends from my roth

Comment: United States, or some other country?

Comment: Just speculating, but explicitly rolling funds from one IRA directly to another is probably the most tax-efficient way to do what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: @keshlam _Rolling over_ funds from one IRA into another is not the same as _making_ a contribution to an IRA, and _deducting_ the contribution is a different issue altogether.

Comment: Withdrawing from it be while depositing into another sounds like rollover to me, and I don't think there is any way to get more tax avoidance than the IRAs already provide. If you have a better answer,  I'm interested...

Comment: @keshlam Read IRS Publications 590a and 590b. There _is_ a difference between a _rollover_ from one IRA into another, and taking a _distribution_ from one IRA and making a _contribution_ to another IRA. These words have specific meanings as far as US tax laws are concerned, and they do not have the meanings for tax law purposes that you are ascribung to them based on what you are "hearing".

Answer (score 2):

The law says that you cannot make a *contribution* (whether tax-deductible or not) to a Traditional IRA for any year unless you (or your spouse if you are filing a joint tax return) have taxable *compensation* (income earned from the sweat of your brow such as wages, salary, self-employment income, commissions on sales, and also alimony or separate maintenance payments received under a divorce decree, etc) during that year, *and* you will not be 70.5 years old by the end of the year for which you are making the contribution. The contribution, of course, can be made up to Tax Day of the following year, and is limited to the lesser of the total compensation and $5500 ($6500 for people over 50).  Assuming that you are OK on the compensation and age issue, yes, you *can* make a contribution to a Traditional IRA for an year in which you take a distribution from a Roth IRA. Whether you can *deduct* the Traditional IRA contribution depends on other factors such as your income and whether or not you or your spouse is covered by a workplace retirement plan.